# Batch Banner colored only

Tags: batch, colors, echo

I would like to have the banner that I call always in red let's say and all the other text be white.
How can I do ?

Thank you.

```
:BANNER

CLS

echo                   ___  _  _____   
echo                  / _ \/ \/ / _ \  
echo                 / ___/    /   _/
echo                /_/  /_/\_/_/\_\     
echo -----------------------------------------------

EXIT /B 0
```

Comment: you can use ANSI for that. But it has been a long time since I worked with that.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048509/how-to-echo-with-different-colors-in-the-windows-command-line